# Spring Boot webapp localhost only

Tags: java, spring-boot, localhost

Is there a way to keep the used port closed for a Spring Boot webapp? Currently, I can access from localhost and from the rest of the machines in the local network. The objective is to only be able to access the webapp locally.

Comment: Set up a firewall to block non-local connections?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alright, other than setting up a firewall, you can bind your server to localhost.

This is done by placing

```
server.address=127.0.0.1
```

Inside the application.properties file in resources

Explanation about this and additional allowed values can be found in the following resource: (for "embedded server" specific parameters, see section "**EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION(ServerProperties)** "

[allowed values in application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @Dani Cuesta's answer:

you add the: `server.address=127.0.0.1`

Explanation about this and additional allowed values can be found in the following resource: (for "embedded server" specific parameters, see section "**EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION(ServerProperties)** "

[allowed values in application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: I added this to to @Dani Cuesta's answer.