# Docker with "--network host" does not allow to access to port of application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-network

I have Spring Boot app inside docker and I am running my app like this:

```
docker run  --rm --network host --name myapp1 myapp
```

But when i am trying to access it from host machine it fails:

```
my_machine:~ root$ curl localhost:8081/someendpoint -v
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 8081 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8081 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8081: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081: Connection refused
```

It is not clear for me - why it is not working ?
It works fine from inside of docker.
Also myapp have no problems with connection to external docker images/internet.
Please help.

Comment: try `docker run  -p 8081:8081 --network host --name myapp1 myapp`

Comment: is the container runnging? whats the response when you run `docker ps`? or try `docker exec -it myapp1 sh -c "curl localhost:8081`

Comment: You shouldn't normally need host networking.  Does removing the `--net host` option, and adding in a `-p 8081:8081` to publish the service's port, improve things?  Are there any hints in the container's logs as to where it's starting up?

Comment: Hi @silentsudo! In that case docker just will ignore -p 8081:8081  part and will start container with host option.

Comment: Hi @Adiii! Container is properly running. And spring boot app is accessible from inside of container.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze! Yes, if I only wanted to have access to 8081 port inside docker I would choose this, but I also need communication to Internet/Other docker images(mongo,redis, etc) from inside of the container. So host option allows me all of that, except port 8081 of application.

Comment: @AlfredMoon are running the container on window host?

Comment: @Adiii sorry, I think I did not understand your question. You mean is my host OS  Windows OS ? If so - not, my host machine has Mac OS.

Comment: okay so might be the case the application bind with `localhost` only.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192242/spring-boot-webapp-localhost-only

Comment: @Adiii It is a good point, but i do not have any bindings like from provided link. All I have in config regarding connectivity is server.port: 8081 in my application.yml.

Comment: okay `docker-machine ip` try this if that works on mac then use the return IP adress

Comment: @Adiii I do not use docker-machine. You think problem relates to the Mac OS and I should go for docker-machine ?

Comment: if the app working inside container that something wrong binding host

Comment: Hey @AlfredMoon, have you managed to fix the problem, I have similar one and I have no clue what to do next. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

From https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

Since you [said you were using macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836840/docker-with-network-host-does-not-allow-to-access-to-port-of-application#comment111180747_62836840), `--network host` will not work properly. I believe the underlying reason is that, outside of Linux, a virtual machine is used to host the containers. The host whose network the container shares is the VM's, not the physical host's.