# Spring Boot Restricit for Local Access

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application behind Nginx and exposes a set of APIs as a https service. My security team has asked me to make sure that the port the Spring Boot application runs on (let's say 8080) is only interfaced via NGINX and people cannot bypass NGINX and directly access the service.

One way to do this is to have a local firewall installed and block the port (8080).

Is there anything within Spring Boot to make sure it is interfaced and accessed via localhost or 127.0.0.1 only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot webapp localhost only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192242/spring-boot-webapp-localhost-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `server.address` in application.properties to bind the server to 127.0.0.1 only.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server-properties for reference.